# Why in this example uploaded_by which is (uploaded_by_id) gets passed to DB as NULL?

Tags: python, django

why uploade_by_id is not set to user ID? want to map uploaded files to the user which uploads.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Profile(models.Model):
    CUSTOMER_TYPE = (
        ('Business', 'Business'),
        ('Personal', 'Personal'),
        )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer_type = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=CUSTOMER_TYPE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Document(models.Model):
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    document_name = models.FileField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Where do you set it to the logged in user? Models are request-unaware, so that means they do not know anything about logged in users. Can you share your view where you create the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the user of the object in the view. Models are request-unaware. So you should rewrite the view to:

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.uploaded_by = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'File successfully uploaded')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/upload.html', context)
```

In the form you exclude the `uploaded_by` field:

```
class UploadFileFOrm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        exclude = ['uploaded_by']
```